# Rails 3 Ajaxful_rating Styling Issue

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, styling, rating-system

I'm using the [ajaxful_rating](https://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating/) gem for a user rating system in my rails app and I came across a weird styling issue:

[image: Too many stars for ajaxful_rating]

As you can see there's much too many stars, there shouldn't be more than 5. I used Ajaxful_rating before in a previous app and didn't run into this problem. I recently started using Twitter Boostrap but as far as I can tell there aren't any styling conflicts as I removed every css link except the one needed for ajaxful_rating and I had the same issue.

Here's my view:

```
<dl>
   <% Upload.by_ratings.limit(5).each do |upload| %>
     <dt><%= link_to truncate(upload.name, :length => 55), upload%></dt>
     <dd><%= upload.user.username %> - <%= ratings_for upload, :static %></dd>
   <% end %>
</dl>
```

Has anybody ran into this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was directly linking to the css in my layout. I had forgotten that I needed to call the helper method `ajaxful_rating_style` instead.

Answer (score 0):

place <%= ajaxful_rating_style %>  in your javascripts.